# Google Analytics Hover Event Tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

This is how I'm tracking on click events with GA Universal Analytics. How do I do this with hover?

```
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', {'nonInteraction': 1, 'eventLabel': 'bottom-cta', 'page': document.URL, 'eventValue': 0});
```

is it just this?

```
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'hover', {'nonInteraction': 1, 'eventLabel': 'bottom-cta', 'page': document.URL, 'eventValue': 0});
```

Comment: Did you try with [Google Tag Manager](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/12/12/track-hover-events-google-tag-manager/)?

Comment: Hey balintpekker I didn't. Is that the only way to handle a hover event? Can you not do it with Universal Analytics?

Comment: Well you can try to track the event [with Universal Analytics through Google Tag Manager](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iknwOXX7jAs). If you can find another solution I would gladly see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To track event hover, you still need to add the proper JavaScript. For example if you were using jQuery:

```
$("#someID").mouseover(function(){
    ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'hover', ...);
)}
```

The main point being that the GA event parameters don't define the logic of the event. It's still JavaScript in the end that does that.

Comment: I couldn't find 'hover' in the documentation anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: "hover" is just a word to describe the action that triggers your event. It doesn't do anything on its own, and has no power to alter the implementation of your event. The implementation of the hover comes through the Javascript that controls and triggers the event.

Comment: nyuen I understood that from the beginning. I left out the on hover jQuery code I used. Thanks though for the communication.

Comment: Another suggestion is that you might want to add a setTimeout around the event firing so that unintentional hovers don't trigger the event.

Comment: That's a good idea, I guess 500 ms would be good enough right?

Comment: that's perfect. :) That's what I've used in the past.

Comment: This can create inaccurate result as some users like to move their mouse around randomly, it could trigger multiple events under a second. Consider adding a debounce time like 2 second to indicate a significant hover